# How do we protect digital data (whether in critical online/offline data centre or personal disk) from man-made EMPs?

Tags: datacenter

How do we protect digital data (whether in critical online/offline data centre or personal disk) from man-made EMPs, such as nuclear EMPs, non-nuclear EMPs weapons, etc.

Is  [E1 EMP](https://republicans-oversight.house.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Pry-Statement-5-13-EMP.pdf) indefensible?

Comment: The most obvious answer is to not store the data on magnetic media ....

Comment: @schroeder - Non-magnetic media such as flash drives would be at risk as well.

Comment: Uh, there are more than flash drives that are non-magnetic

Comment: @schroeder thank you for referring the post. The post was more than 9 years ago. The first answer mentions pressed CD as one alternative. Is m-disk the best optical disc tech we can get in 2021?

Comment: This has been covered quite well by other sources: https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+storage+resistant+to+emp

Comment: @schroeder - The point was that it was not sufficient for you to merely state non-magnetic.

Comment: @schroeder should I be worried about the potential scenario that it will probably be very hard to find software and hardware reading/encrypting/decrypting those CDs,DVDs,or m-disk in the future?

Comment: That's always a worry when you are talking about ***long term storage***. But that has nothing to do with EMP. That's a completely different issue.

Comment: I'm curious, is this background research for an apocalyptic science fiction story? Even in relative near terms, it's not uncommon for labs to have to scramble for old equipment like: 3 ½ disks, 5 ¼ floppies, or even Jazz drives. Then there's the truly archaic 8 inch floppy and countless Tape systems. Even then we're only talking a handful of decades.

Comment: @user10216038 Tape is magnetic and will be affected by EMPs? I am genuinely interested in how to reduce the risks in case of catastrophic events / black swan happening.. so what is your suggestion?

Comment: I can't give you any good answers for EMP planning. I will note however that EMP is Electro Magnetic Pulse, this is NOT a magnetic pulse it's a radio frequency RF field pulse. The primary threat is to unshielded electronics via induced electric signals that fry the components. **It is not a specific threat to magnetic media**, although if the intensity is high enough it too may be effected.

Comment: @user10216038 I cannot easily find accessible information about the science of EMPs. The wiki page of EMPs contains little information. If what you said is true, the name of EMP seems misleading

Comment: https://www.cisa.gov/sites/default/files/publications/19_0307_CISA_EMP-Protection-Resilience-Guidelines.pdf  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse